# MiKTeX Setup Wizard ignores --user-install

Tags: packages, installing, miktex2.9

I am trying to set up a MiKTeX installation for Multiple Users on the same PC (OS: Windows 10), where the user installed packages get installed into a shared directory. On [MiKTeX Documentation](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/setupwiz.html) there is a description stating that the options --user-install allows specification of the installation destination for packages installed by the user.

I have tried to install in the Command Prompt as Administrator using the following:
`basic-miktex-2.9.7031-x64.exe ^
--shared ^
--user-install=^<PROGRAMDATA^>\texmf`

The "%PROGRAMDATA%\texmf" directory (expand to "C:\ProgramData\texmf" in Windows 10) is TDS compliant, but still after installation completion the default directory for user installed packages ends up in "%APPDATA%\MiKTeX\2.9" (this expands to "C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9" in W10). Which means that user installed packages are not shared, but that the same package will get installed multiple times (once per user).

Does anyone know how to fix this? I would expect it to be possible to have a shared location for user installed packages.

Comment: That's a question for the miktex issue tracker: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will submit it there.

Comment: The official answer from Christian Schenk (author and principal developer of the popular MiKTeX distribution of TeX): "The --user-install option has no effect when installing MiKTeX system-wide. Maybe we can fix it in one of the next releases.".

Comment: Seems to be fixed now: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/312

Comment: @moewe Indeed it has been fixed and I have tested it on Windows 10 within my University. Installed packages are now shared from one location amongst users when specifying the option --user-install.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a much easier way to install MikTex.**

Just install chocolatey on your windows 10. Refer: https://chocolatey.org/

Then go ahead to command prompt and run it as an administrator, then type in: **choco install miktex**

Comment: Nice remark, but not useful for Organisations such as Universities. Definitely an option for private users.